# Dual ComboBox selection dependency

Tags: delphi, combobox

I would like to have a 2 drop down combobox with the following items:

- Combo1: 
  Pets
  Fruits.
- Combo2:
  If Pets is picked then combobox2items.Add:
  Dog, Cat, Chicken

If Fruits is picked then combobox2items.Add:
Melon, Orange, Apple

So I try to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('Pets');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('Fruits');
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = 1) then 
    ComboBox2.Items.Add('Dog');
  ComboBox2.Items.Add('Cat'); 
  ComboBox2.Items.Add('Chicken');

  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = 2) then 
    ComboBox2.Items.Add('Melon');
  ComboBox2.Items.Add('Orange'); 
  ComboBox2.Items.Add('Apple');    
end;
```

My code is not working. How to figure this out in simple way?

Comment: Ah,, sorry for thread title, i mean dual combo, not memo :(

Comment: How is it not working - compiler bug? What are you seeing when you run it and how is it different to what you expect to see?

Comment: Please read about `begin` and `end` and the difference between single and compound statements. I urge you to consult the Delphi language guide.

Comment: To elaborate on @DavidHeffernan 's comment: Your IFs in ComboBox2Change only add the first item ('Dog' and 'Melon'). You need to surround a block of statements that are governed by an IF clause with BEGIN and END; .

Comment: @FLClover What Bianca really needs to do is read the Delphi language guide. Learning a language by dribs and drabs and trial and error is not enough. Need a firm base too.

Comment: Thank you all for your attention. I am a script kiddies, start to write code based on search engine on internet. @DavidHeffernan, thank you sir, you motivate me a lot ;). This is your same second words you said to me about to 'read the book' :D

Comment: So please take David's advice. It's going to help your understanding a lot and it will help improve your skills making you more valuable to employers, clients and - let's not forget those - colleagues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use begin..end like this:

```
if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = 1 then
begin 
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Dog');
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Cat'); 
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Chicken');
end;

if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = 2 then 
begin
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Melon');
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Orange'); 
  ComboBox2.Items.Add ('Apple');
end;
```

Also you need to clear the combobox before adding in the new items;

Comment: There a some additional promblems Itemindex is based 0 and the event seem s to be assigned to the wrong combobox `ComboBox2Change`

Comment: Thank you so much @Keith Miller. Finally i got it working based on this script.

Comment: procedure TForm1.ccombo1Change(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    
      if ccombo1.ItemIndex = 0 then
      begin
        ccombo2.Items.BeginUpdate;
        ccombo2.Items.Clear;
        ccombo2.Items.Add('Dog');
        ccombo2.Items.Add('Cat');
        ccombo2.Items.Add('Chicken');
        ccombo2.Items.EndUpdate;
      end;

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Combo Box dependencies, I like to build a Dictionary that represents these dependencies. Basically, you have your Dictionary keep the items of ComboBox1 as keys. When ComboBox1 changes, you re-assign ComboBox2's Items property to the StringList behind the selected Key. This saves you the trouble of removing/adding individual strings every time ComboBox1's index is changed.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FComboBoxDependencies := TDictionary<string,TStringList>.Create;

  FComboBoxDependencies.Add('Pets',TStringList.Create);
  FComboBoxDependencies['Pets'].Add('Dog');
  FComboBoxDependencies['Pets'].Add('Cat');
  FComboBoxDependencies['Pets'].Add('Chicken');

  FComboBoxDependencies.Add('Fruit',TStringList.Create);
  FComboBoxDependencies['Fruits'].Add('Orange');
  FComboBoxDependencies['Fruits'].Add('Apple');
  FComboBoxDependencies['Fruits'].Add('Melon');

  //Trigger Change Event at start to display the selected Key
  ComboBox1Change(self);
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox2.Items := FComboBoxDependencies[ComboBox1.Text];   //Grab Items to be displayed from dictionary
  ComboBox2.ItemIndex := 0;          //Set Itemindex to 0 to show first item
end;
```

Of course, this can be refined and tweaked to be more reliable, but the core of this works pretty good.

Comment: To avoid trouble for the OT you should change *Fruit* to *Fruits* and  fill and initialize Combobox1 as first step in `FormCreate`. The usage of generics might overwhelm someone with little experience.

Comment: I like this style. Will need to learn more about this. But for now, it's kinda too expert for me.

Comment: `(1)` Don't you need to Free `FComboBoxDependencies`? also will the `TStringList.Create` instance be destroyed by the dictionary object itself? `(2)` Id probably use `ComboBox2.Items.Assign(FComboBoxDependencies[[ComboBox1.Text]])` and the `ComboBox2.Items.Clear` is not needed.

Comment: Well naturally I need to free FComboBoxDependencies at some point. I didn't do it here for the sake of brevity. IIRC TDictionary's destructor also calls Free for it's contents, but I can't seem to find a realiable source for that now. The Clear is not needed, you're right. I had that in there from an earlier version of that snippet. :)